# Json property not coming in Order from Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

i am trying to query like below,

```
OPT_VAR JSONB;
select 
json_build_object('CustomerProfile',t) into OPT_VAR 
from
(
select firstName,LastName,Type,Gender
from TABLE_NAME
)t;
```

My expected output like

```
{
    "CustomerProfile": {
        "firstName": "Sam",
        "LastName": "Smith",
        "Type": "A1",
        "Gender": "Male"
        }
}
```

But i am getting something like,

```
{
    "CustomerProfile": {
        "firstName": "Sam",
         "Gender": "Male",
        "LastName": "Smith",
        "Type": "A1"
        }
}
```

My only concern is order of the json property.

Comment: Use `json` instead of `jsonb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition at json.org says:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

So you should not depend on the order of keys in JSON. That's probably why Postgres does not care about the order in the JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

in the comment as mentioned by [a-horse-with-no-name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)

`OPT_VAR JSON;` instead of `OPT_VAR JSONB;`